# SQL Server for last 12 months with begin_date and end_date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I'm having trouble to display the last 12 months for each record, can anyone help?
Right now I can only display one month for each record.

```
DECLARE @DateEnd as DATETIME = DATEADD(month,((YEAR(getdate())-1900)*12) + MONTH(getdate())-1,-1)
--             SET @DateEnd =  '20191130'

DECLARE @Frequency_List table (FREQUENCY_ID char(3)); INSERT into @Frequency_List values ('118')    --                ('111'),('118'),('110')        --             'MTD','QTD','YTD'

DECLARE @Entity_List table (ENTITY_NAME char(50)); INSERT into @Entity_List values 
('F1000'),('R2202'),('R528'),('R810'),('R567'),('R402I'),('R508'),('F1000'),('A950A'),('R557'),('R559'),('R560'),('TBNOBL'),('ALTACORP'),('R590RVME'),('Z490'),('R5070'),('R591'),('R710')

select    P.PORTF_CODE, F.EXT_NAME, REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), AKRE.BEGIN_DATE, 102), '.', '-') as 'BEGIN_DATE', REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), AKRE.END_DATE, 102), '.', '-') as 'END_DATE', 
                                ISNULL(AKRE.PTF_END_OAD,0) 'PTF End Duration', ISNULL(AKRE.BMK_END_OAD,0) 'BMK End Duration', (ISNULL(AKRE.PTF_END_OAD,0)-ISNULL(AKRE.BMK_END_OAD,0)) 'Diff End Duration',
                                ISNULL(AKRE.PTF_END_OAS,0)*10000 'PTF End Spread', ISNULL(AKRE.BMK_END_OAS,0)*10000 'BMK End Spread', (ISNULL(AKRE.PTF_END_OAS,0)-ISNULL(AKRE.BMK_END_OAS,0))*10000 'Diff End Spread',
                                ((ISNULL(AKRE.PTF_END_OAD,0)*(ISNULL(AKRE.PTF_END_OAS,0)*10000))-(ISNULL(AKRE.BMK_END_OAD,0)*(ISNULL(AKRE.BMK_END_OAS,0)*10000))) 'DIF_END_DTS'

from BISAMDW..ATTX_KEY_RATES_EFFECTS AKRE 
left join BISAMDW..PORTFOLIO P on P.PORTF_ID = AKRE.PORTF_ID
left join BISAMDW..ATTR_INSTRUMENT AI on AI.ATINS_ID = AKRE.ATINS_ID
left join [BISAMDW].[dbo].[UD_GROUP] GRP on AKRE.USER_DEFINED_GROUP_ID=GRP.USER_DEFINED_GROUP_ID
left join BISAMDW..T_FREQUENCY F on F.FREQUENCY_ID = AKRE.FREQUENCY_ID

where AKRE.END_DATE = @DateEnd and P.PORTF_NAME in ( select ENTITY_NAME from @Entity_List) 
                and AKRE.PORTF_CONFIG_ID in ( 1 )
                and AKRE.FREQUENCY_ID in (select FREQUENCY_ID from @Frequency_List)
                and AKRE.PTF_RETURN is NOT null
                and GRP.EXT_CODE in ('BARCLAYS','MASTER_2016')         

order by 1,2
```

The result for the columns of start month and end month in [sample result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6dhU.png)should be something like this:

```
MonthStartDate  MonthEndDate
2011-04-01  2011-04-30
2011-05-01  2011-05-31
2011-06-01  2011-06-30
2011-07-01  2011-07-31
2011-08-01  2011-08-31
2011-09-01  2011-09-30
2011-10-01  2011-10-31
2011-11-01  2011-11-30
2011-12-01  2011-12-31
....
```

Thank you!

Comment: My SQL or SQL Server? They are 2 very different RDBMS. From your syntax, that looks like T-SQL, which suggests SQL Server.

Comment: On a different note: [Bad habits to kick : ORDER BY ordinal](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal)

Comment: Hello Kenny smith, welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't see how your query and expected results relate. Are you just tying to build a list of start and end of months for the last 12 months (as shown in your sample data)? If so, you should remove the query. Else, you should show proper sample data and expected results.

Comment: @Larnu: given the syntax, this has to be SQL Server. I removed the MySQL tag.

Comment: If the OP is simply after the start and end dates of each month, seems like they should be investing in a Calendar Table.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Your issue doesn't require sharing a wall of code down to the last `IsNull`, but the DDL would help so that we know the data types of the applicable columns. Please try to reduce it to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @GMB Thanks for asking, so instead of each record only gives 1 month, I want the table to gives 12 months separately for each record, like the example I showed in the end.

Answer (score 0):

*If* what you want is generate a list of month starts and ends for the last 12 months (plus the current month), then one option is to use a recursive query:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        dateadd(
            year, 
            -1, 
            datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)
        ) monthStartDate
    union all
    select dateadd(month, 1, monthStartDate)
    where monthStartDate < dateadd(month, -1, getdate())
)
select monthStartDate, eomonth(monthStartDate) monthEndDate from cte
```

If you are going to use this data several times, then you should store the results of this query in a separate table, which you can then use directly in your queries. This is called a *calendar table*.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would suggest creating a [Calendar Table](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/bones-of-sql-the-calendar-table) (there are 100's of examples on how to create these), if you simply need the start and end dates of each month. Then getting the start and end dates from that table is trivial:

```
SELECT MIN(C.CalendarDate) AS MonthStart,
       MAX(C.CalendarDate) AS MonthEnd
FROM dbo.Calendar C
WHERE C.CalendarDate >= '20110101'
  AND C.CalendarDate < '20200601'
GROUP BY C.CalendarYear,
         C.CalendarMonth;
```

Alternatively, you can use a Tally to generate these on the fly:

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = '20110101',
        @EndDate date = '20200601';

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5)
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, T.I, @StartDate) AS MonthStart,
       EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, T.I, @StartDate)) AS MonthEnd
FROM Tally T;
```